# Heroku: PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I tried pushing new app to heroku and go this error `PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused`

This is my gemfile, does it have to do with that? I'm using spree with postgress. I'm not sure since this is the first time I've tried using spree in heroku but it doesn't seem to be going through. Any help would be appreciated

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby "2.2.1"

gem 'puma', '~> 2.13.4'
gem 'braintree', '~> 2.48.1'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end

    group :production, :staging do
        gem 'pg'
        gem 'rails_12factor', '~> 0.0.3'
    end


gem 'spree', '3.0.4'
gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '3-0-stable'
```

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  host: localhost
  database: ****
  username: **** 
  password: ****

test:
  <<: *default
  host: localhost
  database: ****
  username: **** 
  password: ****

production:
  <<: *default
  database: ****
  username: ****
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your `application.rb` file, try setting this:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

and see if that fixes your issue.

Also, if you already did not pre-provision the database for your app, you need to create one:

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql
```

You can verify the database was added to your application by running:

```
heroku config --app your_app_name
```

Comment: can you try this? `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql`

Comment: I got `TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer`

Comment: this seems like a new error, and most likely it is not heroku specific, but your application specific. See if your app works fine locally or not first.

Comment: Thanks in my case it was happening because I had clicked 'Promote to production' without adding heroku-postgresql first

Comment: Thanks man! This solution worked. Actually for me, adding this line 
`heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql`
helped me.